# How Do I Ensure IE 8 will Never Cache My Data

Tags: caching, internet-explorer-8

I have the following 2 pages:

- check-cookie.html, which checks to see if a user has a given cookie
- set-cookie.html, which sets a given user cookie

In IE 8, I do the following with an empty cache/cookie file:

1. Load check-cookie.html.  I get a 'no cookie' output, as expected
2. Load set-cookie.html, which sets a user cookie
3. Load check-cookie.html.  I get the correct 'cookie present' output
4. Delete my cookies and clear the cache.
5. Reload check-cookie.html.  I still get 'cookie present' output, even though my cookie/cache are clear.
6. Close the IE8 browser and reopen it, loading check-cookie.html.  I now get a 'no cookie' output.

This is documented on the Microsoft site here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/Windows7/Delete-webpage-history.

Essentially, even though the cache files have been cleared, some of it is stored in memory so you need to close the browser to clear the cache fully.  Does anyone know how to get around this IE limitation?

FYI, I am using the following no cache headers:
Cache-Control: no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate,post-check=0,pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache

Answer (score 1):

Your cookie is probably a session cookie and not a persistent cookie.  "The Cache" in IE refers to your Temporary Internet Files folder.  Session cookies are only stored in memory, whilst the browser is running, only persistent cookies are stored in the cache.

There is no option in IE8 to delete all your session cookies.  The delete cookies function only deletes cookies "stored on your computer", meaning, persistent cookies in your Temporary Internet Files folder.

Your session cookies are not being cached, I think it is your expectation/interpretation of "cache" that is troubling you.

Do you have a higher-level problem or that you believe needs to be fixed?  I see no issue in session cookies only being discarded when the browser exits.  What's the scenario?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response Lee.  These are persistent cookies and not session cookies (they continue to exist even after the browser closes in Firefox/Chrome).  The problem here is that users expect the features that are enabled/disabled to be stored in their cookie, since they are anonymous.  Clearing that data should result in settings on the page being reset to their defaults, but they continue to persist in IE.  This is 1) inconsistent across browsers and 2) inconsistent with what a user would expect.  Do you have any suggestions on what else I can try?

Comment: Ah, OK.  Then you're probably not using Expires and only Max-age (http://mrcoles.com/blog/cookies-max-age-vs-expires/) - Now I wish I'd left my statement in my answer about persistent cookies are those that use the Expires header, but I thought it might have been patronizing!